# Strange Nuget behavior dependency resolution

Tags: nuget, log4net

I develop a library and need to share it with my collegues.
I think to share it via nuget.

I create a local package source.

The library have dependency from log4net 1.2.14.0 (2.0.4)

On my machine, goes all right.

On the machine of one collegue of mine, nuget download have a strange behaviour.

When download the library from local storage, the version of log4net installed is always 1.2.11.0 (2.0.0). But in the .nuspec file i explicity declared the dependency from 1.2.14.0 log4net version.

If i install via nuget the log4net 1.2.14.0, and then my library, nuget skip the dependency from log4net and terminate the process correctly.

On my collegue machine there are not any version of log4net installed, nor the log4net dll is present in GAC.

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks in advance,
Giuseppe.

Comment: Found solution by myself. I write wrong version number. I set in nuget config the number 1.2.14, but instead the correct version number is 2.0.4. So, when i add by nuget the library to a project, nuget search the version with same number or greater, starting from 1.2.14 it found 2.0.0. Using the correct version number, 2.0.4, all works as it should.